# App is getting in infinite loop when using regular expression in loop

Tags: flutter, dart

Something strange is happening. I'm using regular expressions that I'm 100% sure are working, but when putting them into the loop, it causes the app to get in freeze state, printing out values tens of thousands of times. Any possible suggestions?

My code :

UPDATE: IT WAS A BIG MISTAKE

Comment: In the first line, you set i++, should it be n++??

Comment: @ShadyBoshra OH MY GOD!!!! It was late at night and I missed it. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed it in comments.

You have to change the incremental statement from `i++` to `n++`

I hope that helped you.